# Heap block modified past requested size

Tags: c++, qt, memory, qt4, heap-memory

**Update :** The error seems to be generated by this line: *line = color;

I get the following error but I don't understand where it can come from:

The error:

> HEAP[testQt.exe]: 
>   Heap block at 0B444FE8 modified at 0B44C6B0 past requested size of 76c0

The line that generates it:

```
return QPixmap::fromImage(qimage);
```

From:

```
QPixmap Interpolation::getData() {
    QPointF pt(0, 0);
    QRgb color;
    QImage qimage(m_width, m_height, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    qimage.fill(Qt::transparent);

    for (int i(0); i < m_height; ++i) {
        m_progress->setValue(m_width+i);
        QRgb *line = (QRgb *)qimage.scanLine(i);
        for (int j(0); j < m_width; ++j) {
            pt.setX(j);
            pt.setY(i);
            line += 1;
            if (isInHull(pt)) {
                color = colorScale(interp(&pt));
                *line = color; //If I remove this part the program won't crash
            }
        }
    }  
    return QPixmap::fromImage(qimage);
}
```

If it helps:

```
QRgb Interpolation::colorScale(qreal value)
{
    int cat;
    cat = qFloor(qreal(9)*(value-m_min)/(m_max-m_min));

    return m_couleurs[cat];
}
```

with:

```
m_couleurs[0] = qRgb(247, 252, 240);
m_couleurs[1] = qRgb(224, 243, 219);
m_couleurs[2] = qRgb(204, 235, 197);
m_couleurs[3] = qRgb(168, 221, 181);
m_couleurs[4] = qRgb(123, 204, 196);
m_couleurs[5] = qRgb(78, 179, 211);
m_couleurs[6] = qRgb(43, 140, 190);
m_couleurs[7] = qRgb(8, 104, 172);
m_couleurs[8] = qRgb(8, 64, 129);
```

Any lead would be appreciated.

Edit: added the full function in case it helps.
Edit2: made the code more clear and removed the useless parts.
Edit3: updated the question.

Comment: Nothing jumps out, but there are some things you can do to narrow it down. Does the error happen if you comment out the entire second loop? (starting with `for (int i(0); i < m_height; ++i)` and ending with the matching `}`? If the error goes away, then that's probably where the issue is.

Comment: @Evanteran the problem do seem to go away if I remove this part. I'm going to update my first post.

Comment: Is this cast legal? QRgb *line = (QRgb *)qimage.scanLine(i); http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#scanLine scanLine return a unsigned char and you are casting it into a unsigned integer http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qcolor.html#QRgb-typedef

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You advance line before you assign color to *line. So when j = 0, you're actually setting pixel 1, at the end of the last pixel on the last scan line you write past the end of the buffer.

Move line += 1 to the end of the loop.